# LLVM Pass segfaults on getAnalysis<DominatorTree>()

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm

I'm trying to build a pass for the LLVM 3.2 optimizer where I need a dominator tree. This should easily be possible by requesting the `DominatorTree` analysis result from the PassManager, but even this simple example crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace {
  struct Mypass : public FunctionPass { 
    static char ID;

    Mypass() : FunctionPass(ID) { } 

    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
      AU.addRequired<DominatorTree>();
    }

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
      DominatorTree& DT = getAnalysis<DominatorTree>(F);
      return false;
    }
  };
}

char Mypass::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Mypass> X("mypass", "My test analysis", true, true);
```

when called with

`opt --load mypass.so -mypass --debug-pass=Structure test.bc`

it immediately segfaults with

```
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -datalayout -domtree -mypass -preverify -domtree -verify
Target Library Information
Data Layout
  ModulePass Manager
    FunctionPass Manager
      Dominator Tree Construction
      My test analysis
      Preliminary module verification
      Dominator Tree Construction
      Module Verifier
0  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d8172a1df
1  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d8172a649
2  libpthread.so.0  0x00007f2d80842bd0
3  mypass.so      0x00007f2d7f63deb9 llvm::DominatorTree& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID<llvm::DominatorTree>(void const*, llvm::Function&) + 217
4  mypass.so      0x00007f2d7f63ddce llvm::DominatorTree& llvm::Pass::getAnalysis<llvm::DominatorTree>(llvm::Function&) + 94
5  mypass.so      0x00007f2d7f63dc38
6  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d811e0e3f llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 575
7  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d811e0e83 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 51
8  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d811e0ba4 llvm::MPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 484
9  libLLVM-3.2.so.1 0x00007f2d811e44bb llvm::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 107
10 opt              0x000000000040d606 main + 4230
11 libc.so.6        0x00007f2d80189ea5 __libc_start_main + 245
12 opt              0x000000000040db41
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt --load mypass.so -mypass --debug-pass=Structure 
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '<stdin>'.
2.  Running pass 'My test analysis' on function '@const_expr'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `DominatorTree& DT = getAnalysis<DominatorTree>(F);` to `DominatorTree& DT = getAnalysis<DominatorTree>();` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! But I'm still confused as the example in http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-getanalysis-and-getanalysisifavailable-methods calls the method with a parameter...

Comment: As the tutorial says:"A __module level pass__ can use __function__ level analysis info using this interface"; your pass is a `FunctionPass` and the parametered method is a `ModulePass`, since dominatorTree is a function related analysis, you can use it in your FunctionPass directly.